# Importing a constant to Vue component

Tags: typescript, vue.js

I'm writing an application in Vue and TypeScript. I'm in the process of refactoring some stuff and right now I'm moving some strings that I hard coded in a template to a separate constant.

What I've done is:

```
export const validationError: ValidationError = {
  lastname: 'lastname error',
  address: 'address error',
  age: 'age error',
};

interface ValidationError {
  lastname: string;
  address: string;
  age: string;
}
```

and then I import it into my component:

```
import { validationError } ../validation/validationError';
```

and try to use it like so:

```
<p>{{ validationError.age }}</p>
```

but I'm running into issues, namely: `Property or method "validationError" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render...`

I've tried setting a "data" value in my component, by writing

`_validationError = validationError;`

in my class based component, but I run into the same error. How do I make this constant reactive? Am I even going about this the correct way -- should I break out constants like these in a different manner?

Comment: Did you make an error at the import while writing the question, or are you missing the `from` in your code as well? `import { validationError } from ../validation/validationError';`

Answer (score 1):

You said you tried `_validationError = validationError`, this would mean you'd have to use it in your template like this: `<p>{{ _validationError.age }}</p>`.

I would leave out the underscore and simply go for the following:

```
public validationError = validationError;
```

Comment: Thanks man, this works. I think I actually fixed it with the `_validationError`, but I had other errors so I just assumed it didn't work. Thanks! By the way, is this the way to go, with exporting a constant? Or is there a better way to save "dictionaries" like these?